# Query and count data that appears in multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, formula

[image]

[image]

SS
Hi, I'm not good with these things at all, so I apologize in advance if I'm not using the right language to describe things.

So, the context is that columns A and B can contain the same values from a drop-down list (because some grocery items can exist in 2 separate categories, but not all grocery items will have 2 categories).

[image]

I'd like the QUERY to count all instances of the value that appear in column A and column B. What should the formula be to achieve this?

So far, this is the results I've been able to achieve...

[image]

... using this formula

[image]

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT A, COUNT(D) WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A ORDER BY COUNT(D) DESC LABEL COUNT(D) 'Number of Products', A 'Categories'", 1)
```

[image]

Here's what changed:

1. **WHERE Clause**:

   - In the initial formula, there was no `WHERE` clause. This means that all rows in the specified range `A2:D` were considered, including those where column A was empty.
   - In the modified formula, a `WHERE` clause was added: `WHERE A IS NOT NULL`. This clause filters the data to exclude rows where column A is empty. It ensures that only rows with non-empty category values are considered in the query.
2. **Column Labeling**:

   - In the initial formula, only the count column generated by `COUNT(D)` was labeled as "Number of Products."
   - In the modified formula, custom labels were added to both columns generated by the `SELECT` clause:

     - `COUNT(D) 'Number of Products'`: This labels the count column as "Number of Products."
     - `A 'Categories'`: This labels the first column (containing the categories) as "Categories" in the query result.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I've updated the formula to include the WHERE clause and the column labeling.

Do you also have any advice for how to make the query count all instances of a value (for example "Cheese") that appear in both the A and B column?

Comment: Thank you for your question, Mae! If you have a new question related to Google Sheets, it's a good practice to post a separate question. Please create a new question, and you can reference the previous answer I provided to you for context: [Previous Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer). This will help us address your new query more effectively. If you have additional details to include in the new question, please add them for better assistance. Thanks!

Comment: @Mae If you find this answer helpful, please consider upvoting it. If it completely solves your problem, you can also accept it by clicking the checkmark icon next to the answer. Thank you!